# How to create a default value for a user defined link when field is left empty by user?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, default-value

I am using a PHP variable on a public web page as:

```
<a href="$user_website">
```

This variable extracts a user's website address from a mysql database when user inserts his web address into a form in his backoffice. If the user has left the field blank, the dynamic link with the variable in it appears as"

```
<a href="">
```

which of course causes the current page to refresh when the link is clicked. I don't want to create a default link in the mysql database, since I'm already using "http://" as the default for this field for purposes of prompting the user to enter this before "www.website.com" for proper linking where it will appear in the public web page.

How do I create a default value that will be placed inside the `<a href="">` in the event the user leaves this field blank in the form provided for him?

Comment: Do you want to add the code that generates `$user_website`?

Comment: use `#`, so the link effectively doesn't go anywhere?

Comment: @MarcB I want the page to send them to a default page, not nowhere

Comment: then a simple `if empty($user_website) { $user_website = 'http://default...'; }` before you output it?

Comment: @MarcB I ended up using your code with some revisions to it, ie `if (!empty($user_website)) { $user_website = 'http://default.com'; }` and then output it as `echo "<a href='$user_website'>";`. Thanks, this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if `$user_website` is empty:

```
if (!empty($user_website)) {
    echo "<a href='$user_website'>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='http://yourdefaultsite.com'>;
}
```

Comment: Well, I had to use a combination of your code and Marc B's above. I ended up using `if (!empty($user_website)) { $user_website = 'http://default.com'; }` and then output it as `echo "<a href='$user_website'>";`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="(($user_website) ? : 'default_value')">
```

That means, if $user_website is defined use that var, else use 'default_value'

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php